# Provide datasets dynamically via GET using opencpu?

Tags: r, opencpu

I am not sure whether I am on the right track with my question, so here is what I am trying to do: I would like to implement something like the data api endpoints, e.g.:

`hadley.ocpu.io/ggplot2/data/msleep/csv`

and hope to be able to use all the great json, csv stuff that's already provided by `opencpu`. Yet I would not like to call a static file stored somewhere within a package but rather call a function that queries a database and returns an R object that the json / csv functionality of `openCPU` can process.

I read this [post](https://www.opencpu.org/posts/getting-started-with-opencpu.js/) and the corresponding documentation. It teaches how to make RPC calls using JS. This is great, but requires me to build a minimal JS app. However, I would like to share or embed a single link that does nothing but returning csv or json.

I tried to create a package that contains a function like this:

```
hello <- function() {
# mtcars will be replaced by 
# whatever the db returns
  mtcars
}
```

But `http://localhost:8100/ocpu/library/resttest/R/hello/json` obviously just returns a json of the function itself. Did I miss something simple / basic or is it more difficult to create such a custom endpoint?

Though it would be nice to be able to pass some arguments using standard GET, I could very well live with parameter less functions and summarize them in a package that contains one function for every dataset.

EDIT: 
Actually this part of the documentation (at the very bottom) about the 'common special case' is very close. All I would like to have is GET request, so I could just have a link instead of js client / call. 
https://www.opencpu.org/api.html#api-arguments